# Runtime unit testing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery, jasmine2.0

I've been testing JavaScript code using unit testing frameworks like jasmine and Qunit. But all these testing framework works only at load time, but I want to initiate the test cases at run time, for instance I want to test an object's value on a button click like below test case in Jasmine,

```
 function btnClick() {
        var temp++;                  
        describe("Test Suite Inside Button Click", function () {
            it("To test true value", function () {
                expect(temp).not.toEqual(-1);
            });

        });
    };
```

How to run the test cases dynamically ?

Comment: I dont understand. Do you want to run the test when you are actually clicking the button manually in the application?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it.

- Invoke the jasmineEnv at run time and run the test
- Note that I'm clearing out the reporter div just to clean up the
  output- which may not to necessary in your case.
- My setTimeout is only to load the div onto the page
- See it in [action here](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/22/)

  ```
  var testFunc = function() {
    //this is optional- I'm just clearing the reporter out to run it on fiddle.
      $('.jasmine_html-reporter').remove();
      var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
      describe('test', function() {
        it('sample test', function() {
          console.log('test ran');
          expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
      });
      jasmineEnv.execute()
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
      $('#myElement').click(testFunc);
  }, 0);
  ```